# composer require consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Tags: php, composer-php, drupal-8

I'm trying to use https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php in a Drupal 8 project. I think I've followed composer ways of adding it:

```
composer config repositories.quickbooks-php vcs https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php
composer require "consolibyte/quickbooks-php master"
```

But the 2nd command returns "Could not find package consolibyte/quickbooks-php".

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using incorrect package name - real package name is defined in [`composer.json`](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/d7775e4ddd36cec2f2affc7bef80e5e9b3c1cc23/composer.json#L2) of this package and it is `consolibyte/quickbooks` instead of `consolibyte/quickbooks-php`.

```
composer require "consolibyte/quickbooks:dev-master"
```

Also this package is registered at Packagist, so you don't need to add repository for it. See https://packagist.org/packages/consolibyte/quickbooks

Comment: Wow ... Thanks! I'm still trying to get used to working with Composer regularly and I didn't even think about the name in the composer.json being different.